# How to display the data instantly when it gets updated, to a desktop user without refreshing the entire web page

Tags: database

Suppose I have a desktop and mobile integrated application working on the .net technology with a centralised database. My question is that whenever an information is been inserted by a mobile user, I need to display that bit of information on the desktop of admin user without refreshing the entire web page. Instantly at the moment when the mobile user pushes data to the database.

Comment: Websockets!  Or fake it by putting an auto-refresh header in the HTML page.  Not real time, but usually fast enough for most humans anyway.

Comment: Ok, I think using WebSocket or triggering a javascript function on a particular interval to server is the only option right?

Comment: You have lots of options. WebRTC, WebSockets, Web Push API, Server Sent Events, ajax long polling...